# Getting Issue on Current Customer Details. Its Related to Caching Problem?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, session, customer-session

I am Using Magento 1.9.1.0 . Now i Have to take display the current groupid on phtml file. I have used below coding. There was no luck.

Tried Below Coding to display the group id:-

#### Trial 1

```
$roleId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
```

#### Trial 2

```
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
$customerz = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$roleID = $customerz->getGroupId();
```

#### Trial 3

```
$session=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend') ); 
$rolx = $session->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
```

#### Trial 4

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session1 = $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$def = $session1->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
```

I have tried all above codes. What I Observed is :

1. It is not giving the current user details consistently and not clearing after the customer was logged out.
2. After Logout Also Showing the last loggedin customer details.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
```

This code will behave like this. If a customer session already exists, then it will return corresponding customer group id. If a customer session is not exist, then it will give you default customer group id which you set at `System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configurations > Create New Account Option > Default Group`